# Use Pandas GroupBy Columns in new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large temperature time series that I'm performing some functions on. I'm taking hourly observations and creating daily statistics. After I'm done with my calculations, I want to use the grouped year and Julian days that are objects in the Groupby ('aa' below) and the drangeT and drangeHI arrays that come out and make an entirely new DataFrame with those variables. Code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import pandas as pd

city = ['BUF']#,'PIT','CIN','CHI','STL','MSP','DET']
mons = np.arange(5,11,1)

for a in city:
    data = 'H:/Classwork/GEOG612/Project/'+a+'Data_cut.txt'

    df = pd.read_table(data,sep='\t')
    df['TempF'] = ((9./5.)*df['TempC'])+32.
    df1 = df.loc[df['Month'].isin(mons)]
    aa = df1.groupby(['Year','Julian'],as_index=False)
    maxT = aa.aggregate({'TempF':np.max})
    minT = aa.aggregate({'TempF':np.min})
    maxHI = aa.aggregate({'HeatIndex':np.max})
    minHI = aa.aggregate({'HeatIndex':np.min})

    drangeT = maxT - minT
    drangeHI = maxHI - minHI

    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'Year':aa.Year,'Day':aa.Julian,'TRange':drangeT,'HIRange':drangeHI})
```

All variables in the df2 command are of length 8250, but I get this error message when I run the it:

```
 ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 8250
```

Any suggestions are welcomed and appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hard to test because your data is not available, but does it work if you do `df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'TRange':drangeT,'HIRange':drangeHI})`? The year and day should still be there because they will be the index of `drangeT` and `drangeHI`.

Comment: @Marius Sorry for the late replay. Didn't add data because the file is over 400,000 lines long. Tried your line of code and got this error: `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`